# Data not listing data dynamically on selecting item from dropdown using AJax , Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page edu_update.php where user can update their educational qualification, what i wanted to achieve was select education first and then courses related to that would list on the second dropdown , i can't see what i'm doing wrong because the data is not loading from branch table to the second dropdown

[image: Brach Table]

[image: Education Table]

for edu_update.php

1.edu_update.php

```
enter code here
<div class="main-grid3 p-skill">

                                                                                <div class="col-md-12 form-group2 group-mail">

     <?php
       //Include the database configuration file
       include 'db.php';

       //Fetch all the country data
       $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM education  ORDER BY id ASC");

       //Count total number of rows
       $rowCount = $query->num_rows;
       ?>
       <select id="education">
       <option value="">Select Highest Qualification</option>
       <?php
       if($rowCount > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['education_name'].'</option>';
    }
      }else{
          echo '<option value="">Education not available</option>';
       }
           ?>
               </select>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#education').on('change',function(){
    var educationID = $(this).val();
    if(educationID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'ajaxData.php',
            data:'education_id='+educationID,
            success:function(html){
                $('#course').html(html);

            }
        }); 
    }else{
        $('#course').html('<option value="">Select Highest Qualification first</option>');
    }
   });


   });
   </script>
```

2.ajaxdata.php

```
        <?php
         //Include the database configuration file
         include 'dbConfig.php';

         if(!empty($_POST["education_id"])){
         //Fetch all state data
        $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM branch WHERE education_id = ".$_POST['education_id']." ORDER BY branch_name ASC");

//Count total number of rows
$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

//State option list
if($rowCount > 0){
    echo '<option value="">Select Course</option>';
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['branch_name'].'</option>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<option value="">Courses not available</option>';
}


else {
     echo '<option value="">There is a problem</option>';

}

    }
 ?>
```

Comment: change this  data:'education_id='+educationID, to  data:{education_id:educationID},

Comment: tried didnt work , still stuck at the same

Comment: make sure request is working on change option and DIV with id course is defined